# Logic of progress code

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, 4gl

Logic of progress code -:

Can any one tell me the logic of following code in progress?

Input (from user) - 123456

Output - One Lac Twenty three thousand four hundred fifty six.

Comment: That does not look like code.

Comment: i want the logic behind the code like:
if user enters any number say 123456 , the output comes in words like One lac Twenty Three Thousand Four hundred Fifty six

or 

user enter number say 234 , the output comes in words like Two hundred Thirty Four

Comment: I want to write the code in progress for this data.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this old PEG post helpful:

http://www.peg.com/forums/peg/200205/msg02479.html